# ошибка формата поля DateField в Django

Tags: база-данных, django, формат

При записи в базу SQLlite экземпляра модели, содержащего поле даты DateField, система выбрасывает исключение несовпадения формата значения поля:

```
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["Значение '' имеет неверный формат. Оно должно быть в формате YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ]."]
```

Однако, поле содержит требуемый формат значения, как видно из консоли:

```
>>> from app.models import Entry
>>> e = Entry()
>>> e
<Entry:  от 2019-03-30 20:39:55.326704>
>>> e.save()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "Z:\Documents\_Works\ГП16\Entries\Diagnostic-Entries-Django\DjangoWeb\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 808, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "Z:\Documents\_Works\ГП16\Entries\Diagnostic-Entries-Django\DjangoWeb\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 838, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "Z:\Documents\_Works\ГП16\Entries\Diagnostic-Entries-Django\DjangoWeb\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 924, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "Z:\Documents\_Works\ГП16\Entries\Diagnostic-Entries-Django\DjangoWeb\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 963, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "Z:\Documents\_Works\ГП16\Entries\Diagnostic-Entries-Django\DjangoWeb\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "Z:\Documents\_Works\ГП16\Entries\Diagnostic-Entries-Django\DjangoWeb\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1079, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "Z:\Documents\_Works\ГП16\Entries\Diagnostic-Entries-Django\DjangoWeb\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1111, in execute_sql
    for sql, params in self.as_sql():
  File "Z:\Documents\_Works\ГП16\Entries\Diagnostic-Entries-Django\DjangoWeb\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1064, in as_sql
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "Z:\Documents\_Works\ГП16\Entries\Diagnostic-Entries-Django\DjangoWeb\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1064, in <listcomp>
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "Z:\Documents\_Works\ГП16\Entries\Diagnostic-Entries-Django\DjangoWeb\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1063, in <listcomp>
    [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
  File "Z:\Documents\_Works\ГП16\Entries\Diagnostic-Entries-Django\DjangoWeb\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1003, in prepare_value
    value = field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=self.connection)
  File "Z:\Documents\_Works\ГП16\Entries\Diagnostic-Entries-Django\DjangoWeb\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 770, in get_db_prep_save
    prepared=False)
  File "Z:\Documents\_Works\ГП16\Entries\Diagnostic-Entries-Django\DjangoWeb\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1459, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "Z:\Documents\_Works\ГП16\Entries\Diagnostic-Entries-Django\DjangoWeb\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1438, in get_prep_value
    value = super(DateTimeField, self).get_prep_value(value)
  File "Z:\Documents\_Works\ГП16\Entries\Diagnostic-Entries-Django\DjangoWeb\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1296, in get_prep_value
    return self.to_python(value)
  File "Z:\Documents\_Works\ГП16\Entries\Diagnostic-Entries-Django\DjangoWeb\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1423, in to_python
    params={'value': value},
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["Значение '' имеет неверный формат. Оно должно быть в формате YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ]."]
>>>
```

В модели это поле определено так:

```
dateReg = models.DateField('Дата регистрации', default=datetime.now())
```

Настройки settings.py:

```
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = [
    '%m.%d.%y',
    '%m:%d:%y %H:%M',
    '%m.%d.%y %H.%M',
    '%m/%d/%y %H:%M',        # '10/25/06 14:30'
    '%m/%d/%y %H.%M',
    '%m/%d/%y',              # '10/25/06'
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru-ru'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Moscow'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

Способы уточнения формата типа:

```
dateReg = models.DateField('Дата регистрации', auto_now_add=True)
```

а также:

```
dateReg = models.DateField('Дата регистрации', datetime.now().strftime('%d.%m.%Y'))
```

не помогают решить проблему!

С чем может быть связано такое поведение системы?
Каким образом задать/изменить формат поля DateField в БД?

модель в models.py

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    entryType = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='Тип заявки')
    entryNumber = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name='Номер заявки')
    dateReg = models.DateField('Дата регистрации', default=datetime.now()) 
    dateResearch = models.DateField(verbose_name='Дата назначения', default='')   

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0} от {1}".format(self.entryNumber, self.dateReg)
```

Comment: Покажите код модели целиком

Comment: Разобрался с ошибкой. Исключение было для поля "dateResearch". Но остается второй вопрос, как изменить формат поля DateField ??

Comment: Никак, у даты не существует формата. DateField хранит объект с годом, месяцем и днём, отдаёт вам объект date и сохраняет в себе тоже объект date. Это просто три числа, у которых нет какого-то определённого формата

Comment: С сущностью объекта даты всё понятно.. Тем не менее, если требуется сохранить дату в БД в виде "dd.mm.yyyy", а система требует вид ''yyyy-mm-dd", чем в данном случае можно воспользоваться?

Comment: Позвольте поинтересоваться, зачем вам хранить в базе как-то иначе? Если вы хотите читать произвольный формат и выводить на страницу произвольный формат, у вас всегда есть методы strptime и strftime — совершенно неважно, что и как при этом хранится в базе

Comment: Правильно ли понимаю, что Django пишет datetime-объекты в БД в только виде "YYYY-MM-DD...."? Если так, тогда можно применить методы strptime и strftime для представления пользователю datetime-объектов в привычном виде.

Comment: Неважно, что Django пишет — вам через DateField доступны только объекты datetime.date. Это не строки. И да, у этих объектов есть strftime, который вы можете свободно использовать.